# Route 53 + ELB = does not work but seems properly configured

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have HostedZone created by Route53 Registrar, one AWS instance and Elastic Load Balancer. I am able to access my application using load balancer DNS name but not with the domain name. I have created Traffic Policy using my load balancer name (I have simply chosen it from the dropdown list).Once completed I can see it in my Hosted Zone record set as an A traffic policy record.

What I am doing wrong that it does not work? All needed ports are open. I read and read answers from similar question but can't get it work for me..

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: The page is unavailable, we were not able to find IP of the server hosting the page. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

When I ping the domain it somehow translates it into IP but no packets are being sent back. How can I assess if this is correct IP? Is Amazon responsible for that since the domain has been purchased there?